# Take a word on a line using bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

I'm new in writting things in bash and I need to extract the word beginning with PVX_ * on the line in a document, but only that is after the word that is in bold. But I have no idea how to do.
I know that the question must sound stupid ...
The result must be a list of this PVX_*

```
Chromosome_1.1  43305   .   A   G   689 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=21;Dels=0.00;EFF=DOWNSTREAM(MODIFIER||2492|||PVX_087695|PV_SaI_1_GB_ORFS_1||PVX_087695A||1),DOWNSTREAM(MODIFIER||3976|||PVX_087690|PV_SaI_1_GB_ORFS_1||PVX_087690A||1),**NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING**(MODERATE|MISSENSE|cTa/cCa|L883P||**PVX_087700**|PV_SaI_1_GB_ORFS_1||PVX_087700A|1|1),UPSTREAM(MODIFIER||4300|||PVX_087705|PV_SaI_1_GB_ORFS_1||PVX_087705A||1);FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=41.72;MQ0=0;QD=32.81;SOR=1.402;set=variant GT  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1

Chromosome_1.1  45318   .   C   A   1432.77 PASS    AC=4;AF=1.00;AN=4;DP=72;Dels=0.00;EFF=**NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING**(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aGa/aTa|R212I||**PVX_087700**|PV_SaI_1_GB_ORFS_1||PVX_087700A|1|1);FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ0=0;set=variant6-variant10   GT  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 0|0 0|0
```

Comment: Are there line breaks in-between the `NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING` and the `PVX_*` os is that just the way it came out in the question?

Comment: @dawg In the editor, they appeared as one line.  I just added the requisite 4-leading-spaces to make it appear as one line.

Comment: Thanks @John1024. It makes more easy to see!

Comment: There are no words in bold in your input. [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and include the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using awk

```
$ awk -F\| '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i~/NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING/)print $(i+5)}' file
PVX_087700
PVX_087700
```

`-F\|` tells awk to divide up the line into fields using `|` as the field separator.  The code then looks for any field that contains `NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING` and, whenever found, it prints the contents of the sixth field after this one.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -En 's/.*NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING([^|]*[|]){5}(PVX_[^|]*).*/\2/p' file
PVX_087700
PVX_087700
```

#### How it works

- `-E`

  This tells sed to use extended regular expressions.
- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `s/.*NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING([^|]*[|]){5}(PVX_[^|]*).*/\2/p`

  This looks for a line with `NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING` followed, 5 vertical bars later by PVX_something.  This replaces the whole line with just the PVX_something part.

  If the substitution was performed, meaning if  `NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING` appeared on the line five `|` before PVX_something, then the `p` tells sed to print the resulting line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @John1024 !! But some PVX_ * are still being obtained from other parties. For example, PVX_087705A that you got is on the UPSTREAM beginning and not in the NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING. Could you help me again?

Comment: @user3783397 Yes, I see that.  Try the updated answer.